# I am going to buy bitcoins for the first time from a seller on LocalBitcoins. Please guide me.

Tags: buy-bitcoins, localbitcoins

I am going to buy bitcoins for the first time from a seller on LocalBitcoins. He says that funds can be transferred via internet banking. He seems to have good feedback, 9+ reviews but I am kind of nervous. What exact steps should be followed for a smooth transaction?
My plan is:

1. Send him my wallet address, and then wait for him to transfer the bitcoins.
2. Upon successful transaction, I send him the required amount through an online bank transaction.
3. ??
4. Profit

I hope I am doing this right. Please advise.

Comment: so, you receive bitcoins first?!

Comment: local means local, i.e. hard money changes hands live... if you are going to use banking anyway, you can  just use Mt. Gox...

Comment: If he has a reputation and you don't, of course he won't send first. Either you send first, you meet or you use escrow.

Comment: @Lohoris: Using Mtgox has several issues, the $50 fee for international wire being one of them. A local bank transfer is completely different.

Comment: Related question: [How do I buy Bitcoins safely face-to-face](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/13117/5406)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Meet him at a public place and do the exchange using a phone bitcoin-app and cash. Make sure that his reputation is worth more than a possible robbery/scam.

Answer (score -1):

LocalBitcoins use escrow, so you will be safe.

Comment: You could improve the answer by adding some more detail. Is escrow always enabled? How does it work?