# How do I buy Bitcoins safely face-to-face?

Tags: trading, buy-bitcoins, otc, localbitcoins

I've made a contact via LocalBitcoins.com and am going to buy some coins with cash. The seller is not verified, but as we will meet, it sounds ok:

- I show him the cash.
- He transfers the Bitcoins.
- We wait one block.
- I give him the cash.

Is this safe enough or is there anything I should take care of? Any scams known?

He requested to use my mobile internet, though (will enable Wi-Fi hotspot on the smartphone).

Comment: I guess that waiting a little longer is not possible, otherwise I would suggest doing so.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Shamelessly summarized from this [extensive guide on local transactions](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=137272.0):

- You want to meet in a sufficiently **public location**, such as a pub or mall, preferably one that has an open wifi.
- If you have agreed on **terms** in beforehand, print out what you agreed upon and take it with you.
- If you have not agreed on terms yet, be sure to **check the current price** of bitcoin during the meeting.
- Wait for the transaction to complete and **check if the right amount** was paid. If the other person is willing to wait around for one additional block together that is a good sign.
- **Specify your expectations** in advance: When and where to meet, what each person will have on hand to make the deal, how the price for the bitcoins will be calculated.
- Consider taking a **second person** along for additional safety.

Answer (score 5):

LocalBitcoins.com features a transaction service which guarantees that bitcoins have arrived to your LocalBitcoins.com wallet.

- You get a secret code when the bitcoin seller enables transaction service (escrow enabled) on the trade
- When the bitcoin seller releases the transaction the seller gets SMS with the your secret code
- Ask the seller and if he/she knows your secret code from his/her SMS it is safe to hand over the cash as you know bitcoins are then in your LocalBitcoins.com wallet
- Now you can transfer bitcoins from LocalBitcoins.com wallet to any wallet you wish

https://localbitcoins.com/faq#howto_transaction

Sometimes when somebody has suggested a deal where there the payment is 50% now and 50% later, it is a sign of potential scam.

Comment: One more thing: Meet in a public place like a bar.

Comment: They have interesting services, yes. But I didn't set it up and it costs 1% fee actually, so the question was rather meant without escrow service.

Answer (score 0):

My answer would be: **"There is no way, to protect self from rapid scammer."**

You are, probably, should spent a great time with seller, say 3, may be 4 hours.

E.g. See this thread: [bitcointalk.org: If confirmation takes 10 minutes, how will I buy coffee at Starbucks?](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=359934.0)

Another way is to use an arbiter, e.g. [www.bitrated.com](https://www.bitrated.com/)

> Bitcoin arbitration marketplace Protect yourself against online fraud
>   with Bitcoin's m-of-n transactions.

Before you go to give your money to seller, an arbiter confirm transaction, wait for seller's confirmation, than send bitcoins to you.